# Best way to compare EXPECT result with our true records in Jasmine testing framework?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, testing, jasmine

What are the ways to compare the `expect` results with our true records using Jasmine Testing Framework?

One of the way is to use a static values within expect Parameters which is good for very basic values... But it has several limitations like it does not compare objects at runtime...

How to compare objects at runtime for its validity...???

**EDIT :**

```
it("Read JSON record with Id.", function(){
        result = Database.selectRecordById (STORE_ID, id3);
        expect(result).toEqual(aRecord);   //cValue
    });
```

Here is the code. Now my problem is to compare the **result** value to **aRecord**. I will get `result` from method `Database.selectRecordById`. For now i am using a static value of `aRecord`. I want some other way which is more reliable so that my `aRecord` becomes dynamic. One thing i thought is to make a database which will contain  all true values... but then i manually have to see that... What could be other alternative.??

Comment: Can you give some example code? It is not very clear what you are asking about.

Comment: please see my edited section for code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see there is nothing wrong with static values for comparing result. That is how we usually do unit testing both in Java and in JavaScript.

The **actual value** is what you get **from the actual database/method call** and the **expected** value is a **static value**. The less 'moving parts' you have here, the better. If you were to dynamically load the expected values, that can go wrong as well and you do not want your tests failing if your application because your test data load was wrong. It is also a lot more cumbersome to maintain.

Hope I did not misunderstand your question.

Comment: No... your point matters... but if i have to test lot of codes then how and why should i use and maintain static values/code. Is it a good way to test a very BIG projects or even to test the framework also??

Comment: @DShah: I am not sure why you think this is not suitable for large applications. Can you tell me an example where having dynamic expected values would be easier to achieve than static ones?

Comment: What matters to me is that if i am designing a framework, and if i have to test it, then is this a good way??